# Google Drive file insert() function throwing IO exception

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have one **live** application on the Google Play Store. This application has **file upload to Google Drive** feature.

Below is the **code** to upload a file to Google Drive:

```
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test/"+"a.zip");
   com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata;
   fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
   fileMetadata.setTitle("a.zip");
   fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/zip");
   FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/zip", f);

   Drive.Files.Insert insert = mService.files().insert(fileMetadata,mediaContent);

   MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
   uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
   uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
   uploader.setChunkSize(1024*1024);
   insert.setFields("id").execute();
```

For some of my users, the code is not able to start the Google Drive upload operation. I have the code to **track progress** of the file upload operation. The code generates some exception when progress is **0%**. I am not able to reproduce the issue and I don't have the exception stack trace.

I have following question:

1. I am suspecting the below line of code is generating an exception? What can be the exception and how to fix it?

`Drive.Files.Insert insert = mService.files().insert(fileMetadata,mediaContent);`

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Edited the post to simplify it. Please let me know if further edits are required. @DalmTo

Comment: @DalmTo do you have any thoughts about this issue?